# SELECT within a SELECT? Different Data in single report

Tags: mysql

My goal is to generate a report that will provide me with data to submit to a payroll company.

Our pay periods are the 1st through the 15th and then the 16th through the end of the month and I can easily generate a report that shows how many hours an employee works between those given dates.

My problem is with overtime. Overtime is calculated based on an employees work in a given week. Our week start and end dates are Sunday through Saturday. Here is a specific example of the challenge.

The pay period that ends on 2016-01-31 is part of weeks 3, 4, 5 and 6. It has seven days in week 4 and 5, and only one day in week 3 and 6. I would like to pay (on this particular pay period) any overtime the employee worked in weeks 3, 4 and 5. I will pay them for week 6 overtime in the next pay period once that week is complete.

I need a little help. Specifically a direction to start looking. Would this be a situation where I would embed a SELECT within a SELECT? Since I am operating on two different spins on the same data source ... I am a little baffled.

Anyone have any experience here? Thoughts?

```
Report for Pay Period Ending 2016-01-31

Employee                 Hours   OT Hr
----------------------- ------- -------
Joe Employee             95.00    1.00
   - Week 3 (1 Day)       7.00    1.00
   - Week 4 (7 Days)     40.00    0.00
   - Week 5 (7 Days)     40.00    0.00
   - Week 6 (1 Day)       8.00    0.00
```

This sample report shows that an employee worked 96 hours over 16 days during the pay period ending 2016-01-31. The one hour of overtime and 7 hours of regular time in week 3 suggests they worked extra on hours in the previous pay period that propelled their week 3 total hours over 40.

Business Rule: Overtime is paid for an employees hours that exceed 40 during a week. Weeks are defined as the time from Sunday to Saturday. Payments are made on Pay Dates. Pay Dates are defined as the 15th and last day of each month. If a Pay Period occurs in the middle of a week. Employees are paid for overtime hours on both side of the pay date as defined above.

```
Sample Data as Requested

Employee        Start               End               Week  PayPeriod  Duration
John Employee   2016-01-02 09:23:42 2016-01-02 15:13:43 1   1/15/2016   5.83
John Employee   2016-01-04 09:42:30 2016-01-04 17:58:19 2   1/15/2016   8.26
John Employee   2016-01-05 09:46:04 2016-01-05 13:30:03 2   1/15/2016   3.73
John Employee   2016-01-05 14:03:02 2016-01-05 18:06:34 2   1/15/2016   4.06
John Employee   2016-01-06 10:30:43 2016-01-06 17:14:18 2   1/15/2016   6.73
John Employee   2016-01-07 10:05:22 2016-01-07 13:43:59 2   1/15/2016   3.64
John Employee   2016-01-07 14:14:20 2016-01-07 18:05:50 2   1/15/2016   3.86
John Employee   2016-01-08 09:55:59 2016-01-08 17:47:58 2   1/15/2016   7.87
John Employee   2016-01-11 10:28:22 2016-01-11 17:54:04 3   1/15/2016   7.43
John Employee   2016-01-12 09:33:30 2016-01-12 10:08:43 3   1/15/2016   0.59
John Employee   2016-01-12 10:39:59 2016-01-12 18:29:24 3   1/15/2016   7.82
John Employee   2016-01-13 10:41:16 2016-01-13 13:39:29 3   1/15/2016   2.97
John Employee   2016-01-13 13:39:29 2016-01-13 15:05:05 3   1/15/2016   1.43
John Employee   2016-01-13 15:05:06 2016-01-13 17:25:30 3   1/15/2016   2.34
John Employee   2016-01-14 10:32:28 2016-01-14 14:01:33 3   1/15/2016   3.48
John Employee   2016-01-14 14:20:47 2016-01-14 18:07:42 3   1/15/2016   3.78
John Employee   2016-01-15 09:40:31 2016-01-15 17:19:34 3   1/15/2016   7.65
John Employee   2016-01-16 09:40:31 2016-01-16 17:19:34 3   1/31/2016   7.65
John Employee   2016-01-18 10:01:39 2016-01-18 15:40:43 4   1/31/2016   5.65
John Employee   2016-01-18 15:53:38 2016-01-18 18:38:27 4   1/31/2016   2.75
John Employee   2016-01-19 10:43:24 2016-01-19 18:13:04 4   1/31/2016   7.49
John Employee   2016-01-20 10:38:38 2016-01-20 14:16:09 4   1/31/2016   3.63
John Employee   2016-01-20 14:16:09 2016-01-20 17:55:07 4   1/31/2016   3.65
John Employee   2016-01-21 10:39:31 2016-01-21 18:56:42 4   1/31/2016   8.29
John Employee   2016-01-22 10:57:55 2016-01-22 15:44:03 4   1/31/2016   4.77
John Employee   2016-01-22 15:57:54 2016-01-22 18:11:28 4   1/31/2016   2.23
John Employee   2016-01-25 10:08:57 2016-01-25 19:14:21 5   1/31/2016   9.09
John Employee   2016-01-26 10:45:35 2016-01-26 14:17:13 5   1/31/2016   3.53
John Employee   2016-01-26 14:40:51 2016-01-26 18:31:56 5   1/31/2016   3.85
John Employee   2016-01-27 09:53:33 2016-01-27 18:05:40 5   1/31/2016   8.20
John Employee   2016-01-28 10:36:57 2016-01-28 16:28:16 5   1/31/2016   5.86
John Employee   2016-01-28 16:43:20 2016-01-28 19:42:17 5   1/31/2016   2.98
John Employee   2016-01-31 10:00:40 2016-01-31 16:27:46 6   1/31/2016   6.45
John Employee   2016-02-01 10:45:42 2016-02-01 14:04:03 6   2/15/2016   3.31
John Employee   2016-02-01 14:15:06 2016-02-01 17:45:05 6   2/15/2016   3.50
John Employee   2016-02-01 17:45:05 2016-02-01 19:01:34 6   2/15/2016   1.27
John Employee   2016-02-02 11:03:49 2016-02-02 17:40:21 6   2/15/2016   6.61
John Employee   2016-02-03 11:08:06 2016-02-03 17:15:38 6   2/15/2016   6.13
John Employee   2016-02-04 11:20:59 2016-02-04 17:27:15 6   2/15/2016   6.10
John Employee   2016-02-04 17:27:15 2016-02-04 20:19:34 6   2/15/2016   2.87
John Employee   2016-02-05 10:47:57 2016-02-05 17:53:54 6   2/15/2016   7.10
John Employee   2016-02-08 10:51:45 2016-02-08 15:15:28 7   2/15/2016   4.40
John Employee   2016-02-08 15:34:52 2016-02-08 17:30:54 7   2/15/2016   1.93
John Employee   2016-02-09 11:01:09 2016-02-09 13:11:02 7   2/15/2016   2.16
John Employee   2016-02-09 13:11:02 2016-02-09 17:38:03 7   2/15/2016   4.45
John Employee   2016-02-09 17:38:03 2016-02-09 18:34:20 7   2/15/2016   0.94
John Employee   2016-02-10 10:43:39 2016-02-10 11:25:38 7   2/15/2016   0.70
John Employee   2016-02-10 11:25:38 2016-02-10 17:58:11 7   2/15/2016   6.54
John Employee   2016-02-11 10:16:30 2016-02-11 14:06:35 7   2/15/2016   3.83
John Employee   2016-02-11 14:30:17 2016-02-11 17:25:23 7   2/15/2016   2.92
John Employee   2016-02-12 10:46:50 2016-02-12 17:46:38 7   2/15/2016   7.00
```

I need to pay 5.15 hours of overtime in PayPeriod 2016-01-15 because he did not go over 40 until after the 2015-01-15 pay period closed.

If the employee had crossed over 40 hours before the 2016-01-15 pay period closed, I would have needed to pay overtime on both the 2016-01-15 and the 2016-01-31 pay periods for week three hours.

Comment: Best advice I can give is provide "sample data" for each table involved, then also, based on that data, your "expected result". While you have described your situation, nothing substitutes for being able to see the data. Then, be clear on your desired  "business rules"; e.g. overtime is paid for the weeks that finish (Saturday)  within the pay period.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my thought on overtime calculation:

1. you'll start checking the start date for the period, which day is it? If it is not Sunday, that means you need to pay some overtime for earlier dates? Well, for how many days? You'll always start from the sunday of that week for calculating the overtime for that week. Some useful mySql functions here are: DAYOFWEEK() and DATE_ADD()
2. Then you'll continue until the end date for that period is reached/passed, and you'll calculate the overtime for each week (sunday-saturday). If a saturday is passed your end date for the payroll period, you'll just skip that week for your overtime calculation.